# Is this a decent description of the process for an interstellar drive based on this handwavium/element zero?

Tags: science-based, technology, energy, stars, interstellar-travel

My story needs four variations of an interstellar drive that uses exotic matter (detailed below). I know what the processes need to do, side effects of using them, etc. but explaining them/showing them is proving to be challenging. I’m not sure about a “One Big Lie” to pave the way to other advanced technologies outside of interstellar travel, I wanted interstellar travel tech to be the focus of the story.

The element zero/handwavium used in the story is living entities (I named them Brongel, goofy name probably, but it might change) that have exotic properties. They’re inspired by the amoebic sea from the fictional Darwin IV and the ocean from Solaris (links below) However, the characters only know them in their “crystalized” form, which is a survival mechanism for surviving in a vacuum and hazardous environment. The civilizations in the story are unaware of the Brongel’s sentience and technological advancement. The Brongel are originally extra-dimensional aliens and their ships act much like mobile platforms when on a planet’s surface. Their method of FTL travel is similar to hyperspace.

Amoebic Sea from Darwin IV: https://aliens.fandom.com/wiki/Amoebic_Sea

Ocean of Solaris: https://aliens.fandom.com/wiki/Solaris

The Intra-Junctions are of their design, but with an unforeseen side effect on stars. These Intra-Junctions enabled a monopoly on interstellar travel by a "puppet government" and resulted in secret research and development into alternatives by other civilizations. Eventually the Intra-Junctions were obsolete, thus ending tyrannical control of interstellar technology. But this new technology resulted in the loss of exotic material (or life from their point of view).

Here’s what I’ve figured what is needed:

DRIVE 1 (Antagonists’ advanced drives)

- Does not cause decomposition of exotic material after use.
- No side effect on stars.
- [Incompatible with smaller spacecraft?]

DRIVE 2 (Intra-Junction, large artificial structure; the equivalent of a hypergate or [Mass Relay](https://masseffect.fandom.com/wiki/Mass_Relay) from Mass Effect)

- Does not cause decomposition of exotic material after use.
- Has strange side effect on stars, accelerating their aging, threat of premature supernova.

DRIVE 3 (The “Drive of Today”; made for individual spacecraft)

- Causes decomposition of exotic material after use.
- No side effect on stars.

DRIVE 4 (The “Drive of Tomorrow”; for individual spacecraft)

- Does not cause decomposition of exotic material after use.
- No unforeseen side effect on stars.

After some research, this is what I’ve got so far (messy notes):

**Quantity of ExMa** within the drive’s coils. Massive levels of electrical charge forced through it heats the substance to spontaneous decomposition, “killing” it.

- Superconducting Coil(s) heats substance to decomposition.

**Rotating ring**, several meters in diameter, spinning at intense speed, placed above superconductive coils. Intense electromagnetic fields and spinning creates a tear where a spacecraft can be propelled through higher dimensional space.

- Tearing produces massive amounts of displacement energy, which scientists worry that it may be having an unforeseen side effect on stars, at least within the Intra-Junction Drives.

**Focusing Device** initiates tearing.

- Draws displacement energy from ExMa Charged reaction to initialize tearing.

**Modulator** emulates the effects of the superconductive coils, without heating the substance to decomposition. Allows electrical current to pass through without heating it.

- Brongel in gelatin-state, non-crystalized form.
- Cancels decomposition.
- Only achievable on massive scale, cannot be scaled down.

**[ADV]** Oscillating electromagnetic fields spinning around a quantity of ExMa agitate the exotic matter within, allows the use of HiDim as an unexpressed axis, effectively a dimensional slingshot, to swing around the extra-dimensional plane and come back into local space without having to pass through it, like a relay.

- Eliminates tearing.
- Eliminates need for superconductive coils.
- Replaces ring with specialized rotating field guide.
- Brongel substance in non-crystalized state.
- Can be upscaled.

This is a mix of other fictional drives I’ve read about. I tried to rework them into my own interpretation and modify them to suite my needs, but… It’s probably a complete jumbled mess and wouldn’t be convincing to readers. Is there enough here, or should there be a completely different description of the interstellar drive?

Comment: Do you *need* all this or do you *want* all this ?  Or put another way, do your *readers* need all this ?  Seems over complex to the purpose of writing a story.  If I write a sea faring story, I don't really need the reader to get into the details of how engines work.  Kinda like "Scotty, what warp speed can you give me ?" - no one wants a lecture from Scotty at this point.

Comment: I think at least some of it is needed because readers may want a visual representation of the differences. They might think “How does that work? Show me.” I also might want quite a bit of it. Personal tastes, I guess?

Comment: @astillround7hief Thing is, what you've written is just technobabble... "_Oscillating electromagnetic fields spinning around a quantity of ExMa agitate the exotic matter within, allows the use of HiDim as an unexpressed axis, effectively a dimensional slingshot_" may as well be "_A goat is sacrificed to Yog-Sothoth who deigns to tear reality asunder (if but a little) and fling the vessel to the far reaches of the cosmos_". If anything, the latter adds a little flavour in the way that dry technobabble doesn't (at least for me, anyway). Do you really need it?

Comment: I suppose I really don't NEED it. I was just worried that I wouldn't have something for those who'd ask "How does this work?"

Comment: This is like warp vs impulse in ST - takeaway: there is one racing mode, and one slow-and-safe mode, technobabble just as filler. Your main thing seems that one machine kills, and the other just indefinitely incarcerates (?), so concentrate on using that. If you introduce technobabble, look for two things : checkovs technobabble (if you talk about huge magnetic fields, have someone be crushed by some iron implement that is flung around) and consistent babble - if you talk about side effects on stars, whats the range on that, and is somebody using the side-effect as a main effect (Starkiller?)

Comment: interesting unobtanium. This and shapes exterior is all good, but this "accelerating their aging, the threat of premature supernova." - way too much. it still can be some gravitational waves, bending of space, residual things hitting stars, producing flashes, which can be a bad enough thing, but aging and supernovae - no, way too much